# DRY in Unit Test for Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, dry

From two files test_now.py and test_later.py as follows:

```
# test_now.py
import unittest

class CommonClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def hello(self):
        print "Hello there"
    def bye(self):
        print "Bye"
    def seeYouAgain(self):
        print "See You Again"
    def whatsUp(self):
        print "What's up?"

    def testNow(self):
        self.hello()
        self.bye()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```
# test_later.py
import unittest

class CommonClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def hello(self):
        print "Hello there"
    def bye(self):
        print "Bye"
    def seeYouAgain(self):
        print "See You Again"
    def whatsUp(self):
        print "What's up?"

    def testLater(self):
        self.hello()
        self.whatsUp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I reorganize in three files as follows:

```
# common_class.py
import unittest

class CommonClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def hello(self):
        print "Hello there"
    def bye(self):
        print "Bye"
    def seeYouAgain(self):
        print "See You Again"
    def whatsUp(self):
        print "What's up?"
```

```
# test_now.py
from common_class import *
def testNow(self)
    self.hello()
    self.bye()
setattr(CommonClass, 'testNow', testNow)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```
# test_later.py
from common_class import *
def testLater(self):
    self.hello()
    self.whatsUp()
setattr(CommonClass, 'testLater', testLater)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

What are the concerns about this DRY approach?

Comment: can you fix the formatting?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a module level function as a method of a class is a bit more complicated than that

Comment: What does your TestCase test? Nothing. Why don't you [try reading the documentation for unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying other modules when your module is imported is a huge wart.

Instead, create subclasses:

```
# test_now.py
from common_class import CommonClass

class TestNow(CommonClass):
    def testNow(self)
        self.hello()
        self.bye()
```

```
# test_later.py
from common_class import CommonClass
class TestLater(CommonClass):
    def testLater(self):
        self.hello()
        self.whatsUp()
```

Or you could just move the functions out of the class since they don't depend on anything in `self`.

Or, once your problem grows beyond trivial examples, maybe give up on using the standard `unittest` framework and use something saner like `py.test` so you can use proper fixtures and all sorts of things.

Comment: I have simplified the CommonClass to highlight the question on DRY. Indeed it's more complicate with those setUp(self) and tearDown(self) in the Django framework. The real test files test a web based application created by Django.